# WebService/api consultar processos juridicos dos tribunais

Tags: web-service, api

Bom dia pessoal!

Vocês conhecem algum webservice/api em que seja possível realizar a consulta de processos judiciais em todos ou em alguns tribunais de justiça do Brasil?

No site dos tribunais de cada estado, é possível realizar a consulta dos processos de forma manual, gostaria de automatizar as consultas e enviar alertas caso algum processo seja alterado.

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

**Opção 1:**

Se sua questão é fazer um sistema no estilo JusBrasil creio que essa [API](https://github.com/jusbrasil) te auxilie em algo, pois é a API da JusBrasil

**Opção 2:**

Pode pegar o Webservice da CNJ mesmo, lá eles disponibilizam para você os públicos.
[Documentação Webservice CNJ](http://www.cnj.jus.br/files/conteudo/arquivo/2016/08/04756e85a5af34413f9d6298a44f1ce4.pdf)

[WSDL](http://wwwh.cnj.jus.br/bnpr-web/bnprTSWS?wsdl)

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo!
Esse documento de WebService, é um documento voltado pra todas instituições jurídicas dos estados, que vão participar da integração e não para a comunidade realizar consultas pública :/